# Is there a java alternative to the Bayesian Belief Network Framework "Infer.NET"?

Tags: java, machine-learning, bayesian-networks, belief-propagation

Is the are java alternative to Bayesian Belief Network framework - Infer.NET? 
Preferable if it be scalable(online learning for large datasets), well-supported(last updated since 2010) and open source and easy to write network structure. So all features from Infer.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing here two Bayesian Network Classifiers projects that I am aware of:

- [CI Bayes](https://ci-bayes.dev.java.net/) - active, last release is 2.0, released on 6th of Oct 2010 and available from [their Maven2 repository](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/enigmastation/ci-bayes/2.0.0.RELEASE/)
- [jBNC](http://jbnc.sourceforge.net/) - inactive for several years, listing it here just for completeness sake.

I'm not sure how they compare to Infer.NET, so you better make your own tests.

Comment: Actually they're both just naive bayes!

Answer (score 3):

You should perhaps also consider [Samiam](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/), it is very powerful and well maintained. I'm not familiar with Infer.NET so I don't know how it compares.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the right tool for the job? For statistics and machine learning that's the programming language R. http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

Comment: Only one Bayesian method is implemented in the link that you gave: Bayesian Additive Regression Trees (BART) - so not a competitor.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not found anything that's as full-featured and well-supported as infer.NET. Please update if you do!

I use an old package from CMU called JavaBayes -- it works, but no continuous variables.