# Bayesian networks in Scala

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I'm looking for a library to create Bayes nets and perform learning and inference on them in Scala (or Java, in case of lack of a better solution). The library should be actively maintained, performant, preferably easy, definitely well-documented unless the usage is really straightforward. Free, open-source and commercial alternatives are ok, but for commercial solutions a free trial is required.

An ideal solution would be the equivalent of what in the .NET world is Infer.NET by Microsoft Research, but more documented.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363855/implement-bayes-net/5364920#5364920

Comment: and here is direct link to [weka](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code) (also mentioned in response Łukasz referred you to)

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman: Thanks, but I've already looked at JavaBayes and found it old and not performant, although quite documented...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[FACTORIE](http://code.google.com/p/factorie/) is a young project, but it fits the bill and is implemented in Scala:

> FACTORIE is a toolkit for deployable probabilistic modeling,
>   implemented as a software library in Scala. It provides its users with
>   a succinct language for creating relational factor graphs, estimating
>   parameters and performing inference.

It's developed by [Andrew McCallum](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/) and his lab at UMass, who are also responsible for the hugely useful [MALLET machine learning toolkit](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/).

Comment: FACTORIE might be great, but it's not straightforward - at least to me - and the documentation falls very short of the requirement... +1 anyway

Comment: Does FACTORIE support Bayesian network out of the box?

Comment: I've spent the last 24 hours on FACTORIE and I'm almost ready to run a naivebayes algorithm (I think).  I really like the organization _but_ the documentation is _SEVERELY_ lacking, as @em70 mentioned

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into SMILE. It is free and has Java API. Other free options in Java are UnBBayes and SamIam.

- [SMILE](http://genie.sis.pitt.edu)

  > SMILE (Structural Modeling, Inference, and Learning Engine) is a fully
  >   portable library of C++ classes implementing graphical
  >   decision-theoretic methods, such as Bayesian net-works and influence
  >   diagrams, directly amenable to inclusion in intelligent systems.
- [UnBBayes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unbbayes/)

  > UnBBayes is a probabilistic network framework written in Java. It has
  >   both a GUI and an API with inference, sampling, learning and
  >   evaluation. It supports BN, ID, MSBN, OOBN, HBN, MEBN/PR-OWL, PRM,
  >   structure, parameter and incremental learning.
- [SamIam](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/samiam/)

  > Samiam includes two main components: a graphical user interface and a
  >   reasoning engine. The graphical interface lets users develop Bayesian
  >   network models and save them in a variety of formats. The reasoning
  >   engine supports many tasks including: classical inference; parameter
  >   estimation; time-space tradeoffs; sensitivity analysis; and
  >   explanation-generation based on MAP and MPE.

Pure Scala and free options are FACTORIE (already mentioned) and Figaro. But Figaro currently lacks learning part.

- [Figaro - Probabilistic Modeling](https://www.cra.com/commercial-solutions/probabilistic-modeling-services.asp)

  > Figaro models are data structures in the Scala programming language,
  >   which is interoperable with Java, and can be constructed, manipulated,
  >   and used directly within any Scala or Java program.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Banjo fits the bill? I'm not sure how actively it is developed, but I know it has been around for at least a few years ... (never used it myself).

[Banjo: Bayesian Network Inference with Java Objects](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~amink/software/banjo/)

Answer (score 1):

Some Java alternatives to Infer.NET were presented as answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934160/is-there-a-java-alternative-to-the-bayesian-belief-network-framework-infer-net/3939395#3939395). So, I think basically you're asking about either a follow up to that question (it was asked during the second half of 2010) with respect to Java or fully Scala-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Scala lib out there by now:

https://github.com/danielkorzekwa/bayes-scala